# About data retention objective-c for view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering. If I have a view controller that contains various other classes that have buttons and labels and arrays. And I release the view controller will everything under it be released as well? I'm trying to make sure that I take care of everything as it is created. But I was just wondering if this is also possible. Thanks.

Comment: Not always.  That's why dealloc and release exist.  Anything you alloc or retain in the .h (with @property) must be dealloc'd in the dealloc method.  Whereas anything alloc'd in the .m must be released or auto released when it is no longer needed.  For example:[ [newView alloc] init] autorelease]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the standard memory management rules, then everything will be OK.

[Developer docs explain it all.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW4)